# Developer Jobs Data Archive Availability?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, data-dump

I am aware of the set of Stack Exchange archives (https://archive.org/details/stackexchange), but am searching for a similar archive of all job openings posted to the "Developer Jobs" section of Stack Overflow. Does it exist and is it freely available?

Comment: Don't think so, and doubt it ever will be. That part of the site is a moneymaking enterprise with no community input like in the Q&A section

Comment: @Pekka웃 Note that jobs can be flagged/reported by users (in the sidebar), which I would count as community input.

Comment: @AurélienGasser true, but I mean *creative* input. On the Q&A side, you have a strong moral argument for making the data available because it is created and curated by the community. On the Jobs side, not so much... of course it would be super nice to have that data, but it's sort of understandable if they don't release it for all the world (and their competitors) to see. And of course there'd be major copyright issues with the content. Can't expect employers to license their adverts under CC-Wiki

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, it's not something we're making publicly available (and I'm not aware of any plans in that direction).